# Convert images to TIFF G4 results in too large files

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio

I am converting gif images to java this way:

```
  File infile = new File(filename);
  BufferedImage bufimg = ImageIO.read(infile);

  ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff").next();
  ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
  param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
  param.setCompressionType(COMPRESSION_TYPE_GROUP4FAX);
  File outfile = new File(outFilename);
  ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outfile);
  writer.setOutput(ios);
  // image4j for reducing to black & white
  BufferedImage convertedImage = ConvertUtil.convert1(bufimg);
  writer.write(null, new IIOImage(convertedImage ,null,null),param);
  writer.dispose();
```

I also tried it without using image4j:

```
  IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(1, 2, new byte[] { (byte) 0,
      (byte) 0xFF }, new byte[] { (byte) 0, (byte) 0xFF },
      new byte[] { (byte) 0, (byte) 0xFF });
  BufferedImage convertedImage = new BufferedImage(bufimg.getWidth(), bufimg.getHeight(),
  BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, icm);
  cco.filter(bufimg, convertedImage);
```

Both ways work fine except that the resulting file is much larger than the original gif. tiffinfo (from libtiff) recognizes it as G4, irfanview tells me that the current memory size (image size after reading) is 120 kB (compared to 914 kB filesize).

Am I missing something - how could I reduce the file size of the resulting image?

Comment: Java doesn't support the TIFF extension just yet.  However, you're in luck because support for the TIFF extension is on the feature set for Java 9 and they just declared Java 9 to be feature complete.  I'm pretty sure if you searched around you could find a beta version of 9 that has that feature built in

Comment: So you are converting from GIF to TIFF (or the other way around)?

Comment: @Mick: only converting from GIF or (JPEG, PNG) to TIFF.

Comment: @Craig: thanks for the hint to java 9, I didn't know this. But why does Java 8 not support TIFF? I am using com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter which is retrieved from ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff"). Is this not part of Java?

Comment: Can you upload a sample input file (GIF) and the output you get (TIFF) from running the above code on the input? Note that G4 compression is less effective on very noisy images. But it does seem very strange that the files should be almost 8 times that of the uncompressed data.

Comment: Sounds like your images are reducing to 1-bpp by dithering. The statistical model for G4 compression is black text on a white background. High frequency checkerboard patterns will cause the compression effectiveness to fall off a cliff. If that's the case, then you'll need to use a 'threshold' option when downsampling your images instead of a 'dither' option.

Comment: The image I used for testing is copyrighted. I tried the coinversion on another PC where it made no problems and after rebooting even on my PC the image was converted to a small image. Something seems to have been messed up in my eclipse.
Using thresholding was a great hint. Choosing appropriate values is still improving the quality of the image.